# how to set http timeout using asp?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

This is my asp code

```
<%
http = server.createobject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
http.open "post", servleturl, false
http.setrequestheader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.setrequestheader "accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate"
http.send  "request=" & sxml
http_response = http.responsetext
%>
```

i need to make TimeOut when the response not come in 15 seconds how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [waitForResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms765535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of `ServerXMLHTTP` instance after the `.Send` call is a proper way, I'd recommend.
Also to use `.WaitForResponse`, need to make an asynchronous call by setting `True` the third parameter of `.Open` method.

```vb
Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = 15
Dim http
Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    http.open "POST", servleturl, True 'async request
    http.setrequestheader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    http.setrequestheader "accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    http.send  "request=" & sxml
    If http.waitForResponse(WAIT_TIMEOUT) Then 'response ready
        http_response = http.responseText
    Else 'wait timeout exceeded
        'Handling timeout etc
        'http_response = "TIMEOUT" 
    End If
Set http = Nothing
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also keep using the synchronous request by calling "SetTimeouts" like this:

```
<%
Dim http

Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.SetTimeouts 600000, 600000, 15000, 15000
http.Open "post", servleturl, false
http.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.SetRequestHeader "accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate"
http.Send  "request=" & sxml

http_response = http.responsetext
%>
```

See here for [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The parameters are:

```
setTimeouts (long resolveTimeout, long connectTimeout, long sendTimeout, long receiveTimeout)
```

> The setTimeouts method should be called before the open method. None of the parameters is optional.

Comment: `microsoft.xmlhttp` is a version independent ProgID that corresponds to `XMLHTTP` which has not `Timeouts` method.
Instead, use a `ServerXMLHTTP` instance. See here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290761/en-us to get what's the difference between ServerXMLHTTP and XMLHTTP, especially in ASP applications.
And the point is that OP wants a 15-seconds timeout. Due to your code, operation may exceed 15 seconds. This is not an asynchronous request btw.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin, you are right. I changed to SYNCHRONOUS, which is what the OP wants and changed the send/receive timeouts to 15 secs.