# Recent problems with the MSXML2 library in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, msxml

For several years now, we have been able to use MSXML2 to read RSS feeds from third party suppliers without issue. A couple of weeks however, several customers sites suddenly had issues and the feeds could now longer be read. This was done with the library opening the .xml files directly from the third party servers.

The error messages I got were messages like "access denied", "cannot read" or "system error". On one of the occations, the library refused to read the xml file from its original source, but it read it fine if it was moved to another server. However, if I used other libraries in other programming languages, they were able to read the xml from the same third party location MSXML were unable to read it from. It read from this source fine just a few weeks ago.

On the other site, the error message was "access denied", but it was actually able to read the xml file from the third party location. The error was rather that the xml file had "." in the name of element tags, like ". It did read the exact file just fine a few weeks ago.

Anybody know some changes to that library that can have caused this or any other issue that have showed up recently with this library and/or its use?

Comment: What version of XMLHTTP are you using?  I think i remember something about it having issues when requesting local data (same server). Can you share some sample code and ill run it on my asp classic machine.

Comment: Frank
The issue I have is the opposite, it is when requesting remote data it sometimes but not always have issues. I actually have had to write a .NET program downloading the xml file to the local server, and then it works fine when the xml file is local.

Comment: I just asked my colleague which works a lot on Classic ASP still and said he uses a 3rd party component from Chilkat to do this type of work.  I know its a horrible answer, but according to him MSXML object has issues where if it leaks or bugs out it wont return data.

Comment: Frank Yes, that sounds exactly like the problem I have. As soon as it bumps into anything it "does not like", even if legal by XML standards, it simply refuse to return data and just throws of something that appear as random error messages.

Comment: Take a look at this answer.  I want to make sure you are waiting for a response back.  I remember years ago with Classic asp i had a similiar issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052543/how-to-set-http-timeout-using-asp  .  Also look at the chilkat components they have a free XML parser, and a $150 http component which according to my colleague is rock solid.