# Unable to set customized timeout within ServerXMLHTTP request

Tags: vba, web-scraping, proxy, timeout, serverxmlhttp

I've written a script in vba to scrape the first post from a website after making a proxied request. I've used proxy (out of list of proxies) while making http request within my vba script in order to check out the length of total posts. When a request is successfully sent, the script should parse the first post and the proxy being used and exit the loop.

> Sometimes the script work in the right way but most of the times the script takes ages to complete the operation even when I've defined `timeout` before sending request. At this point I'm highly dubious as to whether I could fill in the `timeout` parameter in the right way. What I expect is that the script will wait upto that time for any response, othrwise it will throw `timeout` error and go for the next request.

I've written so far:

```
Sub HandleTimeOut()
    Dim Http As New ServerXMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, proxyList As Variant, oProxy As Variant

    proxyList = [{"50.246.120.125:8080","198.204.253.115:3128","98.172.142.99:8080","207.188.231.141:8080"}]

    For Each oProxy In proxyList
        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", True
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .setProxy 2, oProxy
            .setTimeouts 600000, 600000, 15000, 15000
            On Error Resume Next
            .send
            While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set elem = Html.querySelectorAll(".summary .question-hyperlink")
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        If elem.Length > 0 Then
            [A1] = oProxy
            [B1] = elem(0).innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oProxy
End Sub
```

***What is the right way to set `timeout` for five seconds?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", True
```

should be

```
.Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", False
```

[how to set http timeout using asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052543/how-to-set-http-timeout-using-asp)

Comment: You are very right Tim. Changing `True` to `False` fixed the issue. Using `False` freezes the IDE while execution and that iis why I used `True`. However, what will be the parameter If I wish to set it for 5 seconds? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arguments are milliseconds, so 5000 would be 5 seconds