# Getting Timed out Error in Classic ASP While Calling XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I'm getting an error when calling a method of an ASP.NET MVC controller from Classic ASP using XMLHTTPRequest.

> msxml3.dll error '80072ee2'
> The operation timed out 
> /createpaymentlink_ajax.asp, line 198

As I debugged the whole code the method calling is going to an ASP.NET MVC controller, but it's taking time to get output from database and before getting that response, I am facing this timeout issue in classic ASP.

```
function getHTML (strUrl)
      Dim xmlHttp 
      Set xmlHttp = Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
        xmlHttp.SetTimeouts 600000, 600000, 15000, 15000
        xmlHttp.Open "GET", strUrl, True
        xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
        xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
        xmlHttp.Send          
        If xmlHttp.waitForResponse(90) Then 
            http_response = xmlHttp.responseText 
        End If      
        getHTML = "COMPLETED"
        set xmlHttp = Nothing       
    end function
```

I'm currently using this code to call method from classic ASP.
I've also tried to added `SetTimouts` and `waitForResponse` as well.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20this%20programmatically%20in%20the%20controller%3A-,the%20default%20110%20seconds%20%28what%20an%20odd%20default%3F%29

Comment: @jdweng, I Tried, But Not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the request timeout for one controller action in an asp.net mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579523/how-do-i-set-the-request-timeout-for-one-controller-action-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

Comment: Looks like a timeout was added 18 days ago to the api.  See : https://github.com/cashfree/cashfree-pg-sdk-nodejs#readme

Comment: @jdweng there is nothing in the question to suggest what they are using, what makes you think its the CashFree API? They said they are consuming an ASP.Net MVC app not a NodeJS one.

Comment: Right @user692942, this is not helpful

Comment: @ArpitPatel : The exception says "createpaymentlink_ajax.asp"

Comment: Looks like the server can't route to that IP / domain. Can you remote into the box and test if the URL loads in a browser from the machine? Otherwise try a different URL and see if that particular server is blocking requests for some reason from your IP

Comment: @silver, Routing is working fine. Its calling perfectly. But, inside that request there is one Database Call which is taking time due to that its not responding in time.

Comment: @jdweng, Its only page name. There were no such Payment flow. Its only generating Links and URLs.

Comment: Do other connections to database work?  We need to find out if the error is due to the connection to the database failing or just the time for query to complete.  You may need to increase timeouts to database.

Comment: @jdweng, Its Database, That's taking time to execute Store Procedure.

Comment: You need to modify the server code and increate the timeout for query to database. Normally the default time limit is 30 seconds.

Comment: You can set the timeout using a different method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055875/1862388

Comment: @silver, This is what i already did. but, its not working

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and help

Comment: I also facing same issue as well as i tried all the solution but its not work for me as well.